# Local lan drive by download

Tags: network, exploit, backdoor

Basically, I'm testing a local network, on which I'm able to use ARP spoofing. I now want to try and infect one of the Windows boxes on the network with a backdoor. I could inject an `iframe` into their HTTP traffic, or a JavaScript redirect, or something to that effect, to get the file to download. However, I'm wondering if there are other methods to do this - which wouldn't be so obvious to the end user and require quite so much interaction from him/her.

In other words, which tools would let me look for the next `.exe` file downloaded and replace the contents with my backdoor executable or any other vectors you can think of?